# Problem with ggplot: labels and error bars overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, errorbar

I made a barplot with error bars and labels written on the bars.
My problem is: I want the labels to appear on the bars and also next to the error bars. That is, I don't want labels and error bars to overlap.

An example with my code:

```
i <- data.frame(
  nbr =c(15.18 ,11.53 ,13.37 ,9.2, 10.9, 12.23 ,9.53, 9.81, 7.86, 12.79,
         22.03 ,17.64 ,18.1, 16.78 ,17.53 ,16.97 ,17.76 ,18.35 ,12.82 ,20.91,
         22.09 ,19.18 ,17.54 ,18.45 ,19.83 ,16.99 ,19.69 ,19.45 ,13.07 ,21.41,
         12.13 ,9.76, 10.79 ,10.74 ,12.43 ,9.65, 12.18 ,11.63 ,6.74, 12.31,
         17.5, 14.75 ,15.2, 13.89 ,15.24 ,17.43 ,15.22 ,14.04,9.49, 15.86,
         8.09, 5.86, 6.68, 7.34, 8.01, 6.35, 8.4, 7.4, 3.88, 6.92 ),
  SD = c(4.46, 4.19, 2.27, 2.19, 5.10, 7.25, 8.42, 6.47, 6.04, 7.48, 6.38, 6.05, 3.58, 3.85,
         6.94, 6.87, 6.32, 4.28, 4.10, 7.34, 7.46, 6.62, 4.28, 5.24, 8.00, 8.10, 7.73, 5.18,
         5.53, 7.96, 7.46, 7.05, 4.47, 4.73, 8.15, 6.95, 5.88, 3.20, 4.01, 7.34, 7.24, 6.98,
         5.98, 4.53, 4.22, 7.21, 4.02, 4.30, 1.96, 2.11, 4.98, 7.16, 8.45, 6.39, 6.20, 7.03,
         6.10, 6.42, 3.77, 3.53),
  x2=rep(c("a",  "b",   "c",  "d", "e", "f", "g",
           "h", "i", "j"),6),
  s = c(rep(c(rep(c("3"),10),
              rep(c("4"),10),
              rep(c("5"),10),
              rep(c("6"),10),
              rep(c("7"),10),
              rep(c("8"),10)),1)))
ii <- i[order(i$s, i$nbr ), ]
sn <- factor(x = 1:60, labels = ii$x2)
ii$sn <- sn
scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

dummy2 <- data.frame(s = levels(i$s)[-1], Z = c( 4,16,16,8,4))
dummy2$s <- factor(dummy2$s)

ggplot(ii, aes(reorder_within(sn, nbr, s), nbr,
               label =x2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  geom_text(aes(y = 0,fontface=2), angle = 90, hjust = -.05, size = 4)+
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(.~ s, scales = "free_x", ncol=2)+
  #geom_text(aes(label=nbr), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5)+
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16),
        axis.text=element_text(face = "bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14,face="bold")
  )+ geom_errorbar(aes(reorder_within(sn, nbr, s),ymin=nbr-SD, ymax=nbr+SD), width=.2,  position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Example of expected parcel:
I want all the labels to be written next to the error bars on the bars.
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does updating the line to `geom_text(aes(y = nbr-SD,fontface=2), angle = 0, hjust = 1.5, size = 4)+` suffice?

Comment: also worth considering, it is  pretty common practice to show the error bars extending only upwards from the bars (the lower error bar being implied but not drawn)

Comment: @JonSpring : with this command the labels come out of the bars

Comment: @dww : how can I solve that: I put geom_errorbar(aes(reorder_within(sn, nbr, s),ymin = 0 ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution and wanted to share it with you:

`geom_text(aes(y = 0,fontface=2), angle = 90, vjust = -1, hjust = -.05, size = 4)`